# Using PHP functions in phpBB template files

Tags: phpbb3

I'm trying to manipulate some code inside of a phpBB template file.  Essentially, the forum descriptions contain some markup that needs to be converted before being displayed.

I am able to display the description using code similar to the following:

```
<!-- ELSEIF forumrow.FORUM_DESC -->
    <li class="row"><span>{forumrow.FORUM_DESC}</span></li>
<!-- ENDIF -->
```

However, how can I wrap the forumrow.FORUM_DESC inside a html_entity_decode() function or something similar?  I've tried moving the {forumrow.FORUM_DESC} into  blocks, but the variables are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best way to solve this, but I was able to modify the code to look something like this:

```
<!-- PHP -->echo html_entity_decode($_forumrow_val['FORUM_DESC']);<!-- ENDPHP -->
```

I was able to determine the values of the variables with a backtrace:

```
var_dump(debug_backtrace());
```

Again, may not be the best solution, but hopefully it helps someone else that hits this snag.